# What is the point of using useState instead of a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, react-hooks

I've learn what `useState` is and how to use it, however I don't know what the difference it has to just a regular variable.

I've tried setting a normal variable in React and it still works the same, but there must be a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between a normal variable and `useState` is that, useState gives you two values the variable and the setter function `setState()` when this setter function is called your state changes but it also causes your component to re-render and show the new state. If you just use a variable then it won’t re-render you’ll have to change it manually. I assume the reason you weren’t encountering issues when using just a normal variable was because you weren’t changing it.

Comment: Please add your answer to the proposed duplicate if you feel it answers the question better/differently than the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

To explain in simple terms- useState and variables both can store a value, however the value inside a variable will reset whenever the component is updated(re-rendered). However state holds the updated value whenever the rerender is triggered.